# what is meaning of "conversion from void to non scalar type string"?

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

I want to send gps coordinates to a specific number through sms using sim900a module and arduino uno when they request from sms like "SEND GPS" and here code is written but when i compile the code  i am getting  "error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'String' requested" .....please any help is appreciated...Thank you in advance

```
void loop() {

    RecieveMessage();

    if (sim.available() > 0)
    {
        Serial.write(sim.read());
    }

    if(sim.read()=="SEND GPS")
    {
        SendMessage();
    }

}

void RecieveMessage()
{
    Serial.println ("SIM800L Read an SMS");
    sim.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0");
    Serial.write ("Unread Message done");
}

void SendMessage()
{
    //Serial.println ("Sending Message");
    sim.println("AT+CMGF=1");
    sim.println("AT+CMGS=\"" + number + "\"\r");
    while (sgps.available())
    {
        int c = sgps.read();
        if (gps.encode(c))
        {
            float slat,slon;
            String loc=gps.f_get_position(&slat, &slon);
        }

        String SMS = String("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:")+String(loc);
        sim.println(SMS);
        sim.println((char)26);
    }
```

Comment: I tried fixing the indentation - next time, please make the code human readable.

Comment: The arduino programming language you're using is **[tag:c++]**, not **[tag:c]**.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your point .... i think there is no problem with indentation @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: @PradeepKuri Oh yeah? For instance, check the `SendMessage` function.

Comment: i am not getting how to solve that please help  with code @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: I assume the issue is because "loc" is declared inside the if() statement and used outside. I am not sure what happens if the if() condition yields false.

Comment: @MayurK the code won't compile since `loc` is not in scope where it is being used

Answer (score 2):

`gps.f_get_position` returns void but you are assigning it to a `String`. Simply remove `String loc=`

Comment: Now its showing error: invalid use of void expression @Alan Birtles

Comment: @PradeepKuri on which line? Please edit your question to show your updated code

Answer (score 0):

```
void loop()
{
  while (sgps.available())
  {
    int c = sgps.read();
    if (gps.encode(c))
    {
      float slat,slon;
      gps.f_get_position(&slat, &slon);
      Serial.print("Latitude :");
      Serial.println(slat, 6);
      Serial.print("Longitude:");
      Serial.println(slon, 6);
    
      String loc = String(slat,6)+" "+String(slon,6);

      Serial.println ("Sending Message");
      sim.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
      delay(1000);

      Serial.println ("Set SMS Number");
      sim.println("AT+CMGS=\"" + number + "\"\r"); //Mobile phone number to send message
      delay(1000);

      String SMS = String("https://www.google.com/maps/") + String(slat,6)+","+String(slon,6);

      sim.println(SMS);
      delay(100);
      sim.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
      delay(1000);

      _buffer = _readSerial();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pradeep, welcome to SO! Please format your code properly and add some context explaining the code and how it addresses the question.